# Swift. Use of 'self' in method call before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class

```
class ChartView: UIView
{
  class: DotView {
    let circleView1: UIView
    let circleView2: UIView

    init (view: UIView)
    {
      self.view = view
      self.circleView1 = self.buildCircle(some rect here)
      self.circleView2 = self.buildCircle(some rect here)

    func buildCircle(rect: CGRect) -> UIView
    {
       let dotView = UIView(frame: rect)
       dotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotView.bounds.width / 2
       self.view.addSubview(dotView)
       return dotView
    }
  }
}
```

But I got this error:
Use of 'self' in method call 'buildCircle' before all stored properties are initialized

So I just want to create objects in some method and then assign it to the stored properties. How can I fix my code?

Comment: I think your `init` is missing a closing brace, or is `buildCircle` supposed to be inside the initializer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't call methods on self before all non-optional instance variables are initialized.
There are several ways to go around that.

1. Change properties to optionals or implicitly unwrapped optionals
   (not recommended)
2. Make the `buildCircle()` method static or just a
   function in the file and call the `addSubview()` for all the circles
   after all of the properties were initialized and you called
   `super.init()`
3. etc. You just have to avoid calls to self before the
   class was initialized.

Answer (score 3):

For solving of this issue it is possible to use these approaches:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var prop: String = ""

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.setupMyProperty()
    }

    func setupMyProperty() {
        prop = "testValue"
    }
}


class MyClass1: NSObject {
    var prop: String = ""

    override init() {
        prop = MyClass1.setupMyProperty()
        super.init()
    }

    class func setupMyProperty() -> String{
        return "testValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure I can do the same with objects instead of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can create your circleView in the function `willMoveToSuperview`.
In this lifecycle function you are sure to have `ChartView` allocated properly, so:

```
override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
      self.circleView1 = self.buildCircle(some rect here)
      self.circleView2 = self.buildCircle(some rect here)
}
```

Comment: sorry I forget adding nested class. I've edited my question.

Comment: so in my chart view I want to create dots, that is related to this char, so I just inject a view of chart view into dot view component, but I want o have ability to modify frame of dots I've created outside DotView class

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander try to use class function

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk, class function will work, but it means I will get rid of other properties like view. So as I need to add view as a subview in the same method, I will not be able to do it in a `class func`